# Android: spinner text color is not fixed despite defining inline textColor in light and dark mode

Tags: android, xml

This is my `xml` code:

```
<TableRow android:background="@drawable/cell_styles_1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Bill type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10pt"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bill_type"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10pt"/>
</TableRow>
```

This is my `cell_styles_1.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:height="2dp"
                android:color="#090808" />
            <solid android:color="#E69980" />
            <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp" />

            <corners android:radius="1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I want the `Spinner` textColor to be white regardless of the device theme (light or dark). But it stays white in dark mode and turns to black in light mode. How do I fix this issue?